# How to write custom filter for transaction management

Tags: filter, transactions, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I want to use a filter to manage transaction with following requirements.

- Filter must be executed just after `Authorization Filter`( i don’t
  want to use `order` explicitly)
- Filter must open a transaction before action method content
- Transaction must be commited if no exception, otherwise must be
  rolled back after execution of action method.

The filter implementation i think looks like this:

```
    private IDbContextTransaction _tx;

    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        _tx = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception == null)
        {
            _tx.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            _tx.Rollback();
        }
    }
```

Then i want to use it for command actions like below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Command]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] CreateTodoCommand cmd)
    {
    }
```

According to docs:

> Resource filters are the first filter to handle a request after
>   authorization, and the last one to touch the request as it is leaving
>   the filter pipeline. They’re especially useful to implement caching or
>   otherwise short-circuit the filter pipeline for performance reasons.

It seems viable to use in my case. If there is no other solution i will go with this. On the other hand i want to try to write my own custom filter type like `Authorization Filter` and put it in filter pipeline.

**Question:** How to implement custom filter?

Comment: Just a though have you thought about plugging in custom middleware?

Comment: @DrSchizo yes i thought but using middleware is not viable in my case(i think so). Because the transaction is for only command action which has `Command` attribute(I will update my question).

Comment: I am not sure if you could use AuthorizationFilter for this purpose as its only executed on the incoming request and not on the outgoing response(but I am not sure if I am correct here as you can write a `continuation` when using await with `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`). The same way Result filter's `OnResourceExecuted` would get executed after the response has been written out to the client, so i am not sure if you are ok with this. If we keep all this aside, you ideally want the transaction window to be small and not wrap around multiple layers.

Comment: Also you would need to take care of exception scenarios and rolling back

Comment: @KiranChalla i don't want to use `AuthorizationFilter`, i wanted to use any filter just like order of it(before all filters) . You are right for `Resource Filter` it  seems not viable for my case(i have misunderstand it). In this case it seems my only option is to use `Action Filter` with setting order(it may be -1000) in the filter constructor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom attribute and set it to your Action.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
    public class CustomActionFilter: Attribute, IActionFilter {
            public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
    }
    }
```